# Multifactorial analysis of variance with repeated measurements-literature

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, references, terminology

What is the difference between multivariate and multifactor ANOVA? Does anybody have any pointers to downloadable literature about multifactorial analysis of variance with repeated measurements?

Answer (score 1):

"Multifactor" / factorial ANOVA refer to cases where you have more than one factor (i.e., categorical explanatory variable).  "Multivariate" is also called *M*ANOVA (note the initial *M*); this refers to cases where you have multiple dependent / response variables.  Googling "[repeated measures ANOVA](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=repeated%20measures%20anova&oq=repeated%20&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l10.1176698.1179368.0.1180776.11.11.0.0.0.0.109.823.10j1.11.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.hp..2.9.623.0.AIWnyIqPNrY)" yielded some hits that may help you, including [this pdf](http://www.statisticshell.com/docs/repeatedmeasures.pdf) (which is SPSS-specific, but may be of some value even if you don't use SPSS).

Comment: Tnx, but why is it the same? I need to write a seminar about multifactorial ANOVA with repeated measurements, and what I found is that multifactorial ANOVA is when there are 2 or more independent variables, and multivariate is when they are dependent. I can't find much material about multifactorial ANOVA.

Comment: Sorry, @MMaric, they aren't the same, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Multifactor ANOVA should be covered in any introductory or intermediate statistics textbook. It will more commonly be called "factorial" ANOVA, so your difficulty may be coming from searching for a less frequent name. If you want some books specific to ANOVA, you could try some of the materials listed here: [Good resource to understand ANOVA and ANCOVA?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2730/7290)

Comment: Is it ''ANOVA with repeated measurements'' same as the ''repeated measures ANOVA''?

Comment: @MMaric, "repeated measures ANOVA" is certainly the same as "ANOVA with repeated measures", but neither is the same as MANOVA. If the distinction b/t rmANOVA & MANOVA is what you are actually after here (that is a common & sensible question), you may want to try reading this CV thread: [Differences between MANOVA and Repeated Measures ANOVA?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13197/7290)

Comment: I know MANOVA isn't  the same as repeated measures ANOVA. Isn't MANOVA multivariate ANOVA? I'm just having problem with english terminology.

Comment: @MMaric, yes, MANOVA is Multivariate ANOVA. That is in my (revised) answer.